# LineageOS 16.0, can't get tethering to work, Samsung Galaxy J5 SM-J500FN

Tags: usb, networking, tethering, usb-tethering

I use 'Free' French ISP. Tethering was working previously, I made no update.

I have another device with LOS 16 that works well with tethering.

After running `dhclient usb0` from my Linux OS, I get my private IP address, `adb logcat` shows:

```
07-16 01:46:41.940  4507  4507 I dnsmasq : DHCPREQUEST(rndis0) 192.168.42.124 00:11:22:33:aa:bb·
07-16 01:46:41.941  4507  4507 I dnsmasq : DHCPNAK(rndis0) 192.168.42.124 00:11:22:33:aa:bb address in use
07-16 01:46:44.221  4507  4507 I dnsmasq : DHCPDISCOVER(rndis0) 00:11:22:33:aa:bb·
07-16 01:46:44.222  4507  4507 I dnsmasq : DHCPOFFER(rndis0) 192.168.42.119 00:11:22:33:aa:bb·
07-16 01:46:44.222  4507  4507 W dnsmasq : Ignoring domain domain.tld for DHCP host name (null)
07-16 01:46:44.224  4507  4507 I dnsmasq : DHCPREQUEST(rndis0) 192.168.42.119 00:11:22:33:aa:bb·
07-16 01:46:44.224  4507  4507 I dnsmasq : DHCPACK(rndis0) 192.168.42.119 00:11:22:33:aa:bb linuxbox
```

- from my Linux box, I can ping the Android device as well, but I can't get network access through Android
- the Android interface `rndis0` is up with ip in the same network as my Linux box.
- I have default route established to the android device as well.
- from the Android shell (via `adb`), I can ping whatever domain or IP.
- in `sysctl`, I have `net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1`

This is some errors from `dmesg`:

```
[ 910.429371] 2 init: 1] init: Received control message 'interface_start' for 'vendor.lineage.trust@1.0::IUsbRestrict/default' from pid: 230 (/system/bin/hwservicemanager)
[ 910.429463] 2 init: 1] init: Could not find service hosting interface vendor.lineage.trust@1.0::IUsbRestrict/default
```

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.

Blokada app is blocking tethering. Filled a [bug report](https://github.com/blokadaorg/blokada/issues/752)